# async await mongodb find filter is not working, how can i make this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

i want the code to not return everything except a specific value in the database objects that are returned but even after putting in the filter it still return the unwanted value. this is the code that i am using. The field that I am trying to remove from the objects is "ss". the filter function is written similar to what the MongoDB documentation has told me to do but i am missing something.

client side

```
this.blocks = await CatService.getAllBlocks()

    static getAllBlocks() {
        let result = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
                .get(`/api/cats/read-all`)
                .then((res) => {
                    const data = res.data
                    console.log('RETURNED DATA:', data)
                    resolve(
                        data.map((block) => ({
                            ...block,
                            createdAt: new Date(block.createdAt)
                        }))
                    )
                })
                .catch((err)=> { reject(err) })
        })

        return result
    }
```

Server Code

```
router.get('/read-all', async (req, res) => {
    const blocks = await loadBlocksCollection()
    let retrievedData = await blocks.find(
        {},
        { "ss": 0 }
    ).toArray()

    res.send(retrievedData)
})

async function loadBlocksCollection() {
    const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI
    const db_name = process.env.DB || 'db_name'
    const c_name = 'blocks'

    const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
        uri,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }
    )

    return client.db(db_name).collection(c_name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not correct syntax:

```
let retrievedData = await blocks.find(
        {},
        { "ss": 0 }
    ).toArray()
```

The correct way to filter Data is like this:

```
let retrievedData = await blocks.find(
    {}
).project({ ss: 0 }).toArray()
```